# Flutter video_player Issue on Honor X7b with some videos

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-video-player

I am experiencing a peculiar issue with video playback in a Flutter app, specifically on an Honor X7b device. My app uses the video_player and chewie packages for video playback functionality. While testing, I've found that the app plays shorter videos without any problems on various devices, including the Honor X7b and a Samsung Galaxy A71. However, when attempting to play longer videos, playback fails on the Honor X7b but works perfectly on the Galaxy A71 and other devices.

**error message**

```
PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error x.t: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(2, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640033, -1, null, [1920, 1334, 25.000002], [-1, -1]), format-supported-NO_EXCEEDS-CAPABILITIES, null, null)
```

**used packages**

```
  video_player: ^2.8.2
  chewie: ^1.7.4
```